# Navigation drawer not open on menu icon click on toolbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, toolbar

I want to open drawer on menu icon click but it not work.see this image what i want to say....

[image]

Following code work for when we slide but not work for menu icon click.

Please check my problem and help me...

Thanks for your valuable time...

MainActicity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    FragmentDrawerListener {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_lay);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
    displayView(0);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    } 
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}
```

FragmentDrawer.java

```
public class FragmentDrawer extends Fragment {

private static String TAG = FragmentDrawer.class.getSimpleName();

private static String[] titles = null;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private FragmentDrawerListener drawerListener;
private View containerView;

public FragmentDrawer() {

}

public void setDrawerListener(FragmentDrawerListener listener) {
    this.drawerListener = listener;
}

public static List<NavDrawerItem> getData() {
    List<NavDrawerItem> data = new ArrayList<>();

    // preparing navigation drawer items
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        NavDrawerItem navItem = new NavDrawerItem();
        navItem.setTitle(titles[i]);
        data.add(navItem);
    }
    return data;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    titles = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_labels);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflating view layout
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            drawerListener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }

    }));

    return layout;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param fragmentId
 * @param drawerLayout
 * @param toolbar
 */
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {

    containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        @Override
        public void setToolbarNavigationClickListener(
                OnClickListener onToolbarNavigationClickListener) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(onToolbarNavigationClickListener);
            Log.i("RAJAT", "I am here");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            Log.d("RAJAT", "click ON OPTION ITEM");
            if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                Log.d("RAJAT", "click here");
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }

    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });
}

static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private ClickListener clickListener;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if( child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

    }

}

public static interface ClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view, int position);

    public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}

public interface FragmentDrawerListener {
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this block of code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
     if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                    }else{
                        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                    }      

    }else if (item.getItemId()== R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    } 
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: in oncreate().  First declare your button and set its oncllicklistener()

Comment: but i'm using default menu button for it like getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: @Garg's : Glad to help you.

Comment: @Erum above solution is working!! may be your scenario is different without seeing your problem cant say whats wrong?? So please share your problem with code.

Comment: Make sure to include the toolbar layout inside the drawer layout or it won't work

Answer (score 0):

```
  final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? Posting only code is usually not enough.